# Is it possible to create a React Styled Component that has a predetermined structure with the option to set the element dynamically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I have been working a lot with styled components in React recently. In the beginning I created a component for each element, so for example a file called `"Button.tsx"`. In this case, this file would return a styled button.
I have noticed lately that creating a styled component can be time consuming and it also becomes a lot of "unecessary" code according to me.
It would have been awesome if it was possible to create one file called `"Component.tsx"` instead that returns a styled component. This would save a lot of time and would also make one file look messy instead of a bunch of files. I have tried this and it works just like i want to (almost).
The problem I am having right now is that the styled component gets rerendered by React since it is called inside of a function. An easy fix would be to just move the styled component outside of the function but that way it wont keep track of the argument that is passed in which is necessary for the styled component to know which element it should render. I don't know. Would this be possible? I'll attach a/some screenshot/screenshots. [Reusable styled component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tp6Ik.png)

Comment: Unrelated to React/TS: It depends on the HTML structure in the component. Not all elements are valid children of other elements.

Comment: Super thankful for trying to help me out! I actually managed to find the solution. You can change the "element" of the styled component after defining it by using the "as" property. Simply create a styled div component for example and then when rendering it, pass in the "as" property followed by the dynamic element that you want the styled component to be. I am not sure if my question was formulated correctly for you to understand it completely but yeah. If anyone has any questions about this problem, PM/comment and I will explain a lil bit better.